# How to access element at index in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Given the following data in our db:
[image]

And let us say I have the following code:

```
function person() {
db.collection('groups').get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.docs.forEach(function (doc) {
        console.log(doc.data().users[0].val())
    });
});

}
```

How do I display to console that **email1@.com** ?

When I call  `console.log(doc.data().users)`
I get this
[image]

Comment: Doc.data() should be the collection of the entire users, so, you just need to "doc.data()[0]" to access the fist element. Here is the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#node.js_1 Also I suggest you to put into async function and await for the result.

Comment: @ChaoticPechan This does not work, for this array is inside a bigger doc with other data

Comment: There you go, you have it in your print, doc.data().users[0]

Comment: @ChaoticPechan I have tried, it throws an error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Comment: That's different, Where are you using this code? This is because the thing I was saying in first place, Firestore works async, if you are rendering your site and try to use the value you won't get anything. that's because basically you are calling firestore API and wait for the response. If you want to access correctly after or while you render you need to tell JS that waits for the response.

Comment: In other words, when you loads the function, your data isn't there, until the API response. This implementation could be more suitable for you: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#web-version-9_6

Comment: @SamuraiWarrior do you have any update?

Comment: Basically, sometimes users will be null, so, to account for that, just add if(doc.data().users) { }

Answer (score 0):

Try without `val()`, the place of `val()` in  `doc.data().users[0].val()` should be another field of element of the array:

```
doc.data().users[0]
```